# Are empty data files in Apache Flink checkpoints or savepoints normal or a sign of problems?

Tags: apache-flink

I am wondering whether empty data files in savepoints created by Flink (as well as checkpoints for the HashMapStateBackend) are an expected thing or wether they point towards problems with either Flink itself, the jobs we are running or the storage system we are using for both checkpoints and savepoints.

Here is a bit of context on why I am asking this and under which circumstances such empty files are observed:

We are having issues with a Flink setup we run in production. At seemingly random (but currently not rare) occasions flink fails to restore from a checkpoint or savepoint.

The error messages logged boil down to something like this:

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.core.io.VersionMismatchException: Incompatible version: found 0, compatible versions are [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
    at org.apache.flink.core.io.VersionedIOReadableWritable.resolveVersionRead(VersionedIOReadableWritable.java:87)
    at org.apache.flink.core.io.VersionedIOReadableWritable.read(VersionedIOReadableWritable.java:47)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.KeyedBackendSerializationProxy.read(KeyedBackendSerializationProxy.java:139)
```

The strange thing is that this

- happens at points in time where we changed NOTHING about the job code
  (and hence nothing about the format of the data that needs to be
  preserved in the check- or savepoints) and
- that the "version found" that is reported is 0.

What is even more confusing is that this happens sometimes, but not always. I.e. out of say 10 savepoints, 6 are good and 4 are bad (not restorable).

I tried to correlate this with how the savepoints look like on disk and I think I see the following correlation:

**Our bad savepoints have one or more data files that have zero length (other data files in the same savepoint have non zero length).**

I could not find much about the binary format of the save points. So my questions are:

- Is a zero length data file in a savepoint something to be expected or a sign of trouble?
- Could the zero length files lead to the exception shown above (i.e. detection of version 0)
- Where can I find information on the format (beyond the Flink source code)? Specifically: What are the versions and how are they recorded in the data? And how can I convert the `_metadata` file to human readable form?

Comment: Looking for documentation I found FLIP41 (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-41%3A+Unify+Binary+format+for+Keyed+State) and the associated implementation ticket. But I think I am looking for a more high level documentation of the snapshot format.

Comment: please mention the version of Flink as well.

Comment: Hi Jan, this indeed sounds weird, but I'm afraid that without an additional context I can't help. Couple of things:
1) You're mixing up snapshots & checkpoints a lot in the question. Both of them have a different format - checkpoint uses a native one (specific to the state backend) / and snapshot canonical one. Which one are you restoring from? Are they reported as successful?
2) Which version are you using? This might at least give a reference to the source code.
3) Would you be able to attach log files from both TM & JM?

Comment: @damjad: We observe this both for 1.13 and 1.14

Comment: @DavidMoravek: I was refering both to checkpoints and savepoints becaue we have the same issue in both cases. In all cases Flink thinks the save or checkpoint was successful. But when it tries to use it, it can not. Also no error messages in the logs of either job or taskmanager when taking the save or checkpoints. When restoring we get the log message shown in the question.

Comment: Hi all, it turned out that our storage system has indeed a bug that causes loss of file content on a semi random basis and empty files. Would still be interested in pointers to documentation of the storage formats for both checkpoints and savepoints (we are using the HashMapStateBackend).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am almost certain that an empty data file indicates a problem here: Flink writes the state that is less than `state.storage.fs.memory-threshold` into `_metadata`. So if there is a data file, it should be larger than the threshold. Hard to say where the problem is, though. Did you check your storage system: do you have enough space there?

Comment: Space on storage is not the issue but we have now confirmation that our storage system has a bug that can lead to empty files as we observed.

Comment: Otherwise thanks for the pointer to state.storage.fs.memory-threshold. I somehow overlooked this. Can you tell whether this apply to savepoints, too (documentation reads like it is for checkpoints only)?

Comment: I believe it is for savepoint as well